# reinstall virtualboxVM but cant find acrhive for it

Tags: virtualbox

I tried uninstalling virtualbox VM but i get this" The package virtualbox-6.1 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

Comment: I have installed VBox from VirtualBox.org and from Ubuntu Software. I have always had the best luck using the version from Ubuntu Software.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of places to get VirtualBox from, and the Oracle repository generally sees more updates … which is both a good and a bad thing.

If you haven’t already added the Oracle repository to your Ubuntu installation, this is how you do it:

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Install some prerequisites:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install software–properties–common
   ```
3. Install the GPG keys for the repository:

   ```
   wget –q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
   wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add –
   ```
4. Add the Oracle repository:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib"
   ```
5. Update your cache:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
6. Install VirtuslBox:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install virtualbox–6.1
   ```
7. Download the Expansion Pack:

   ```
   wget https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.22/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.22.vbox-extpack
   ```
8. Install the Expansion Pack:

   ```
   sudo VBoxManage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.22.vbox-extpack
   ```

And that’ll be that